# Unknown error when running command line Phalcon app

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to run a command-line task, and my cli.php file is giving me this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/htdocs/classschedule/app/cli.php on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Call to undefined method ::gettaskname() in /var/www/htdocs/classschedule/app/cli.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/htdocs/classschedule/app/cli.php(23): Phalcon\Cli\Console->handle(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/htdocs/classschedule/app/cli.php on line 23
```

Here is my `cli.php`

```
include '/var/www/common/dump.php';
require 'config/bootstrap.php';

$DI->get('dispatcher')->setDefaultNamespace('Task');
$DI->get('dispatcher')->setNamespaceName('Task');

$Console = new \Phalcon\CLI\Console();
$Console->setDI($DI);

$arguments = [];
foreach($argv as $k => $arg) {
    if($k == 1) {
        $arguments['task'] = $arg;
    } elseif($k == 2) {
         $arguments['action'] = $arg;
    } elseif($k >= 3) {
        $arguments['params'][] = $arg;
    }
}

try{
    $Console->handle($arguments); // <-- This is line 23
}
catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(255);
}
```

I have no idea why either the Notice or Fatal error are getting generated.  This file is almost identical to the cli.php for another app I have, that runs just fine.  Even taking out the `foreach()` still causes the error.

**Edit:**

[Bootstrap.php](https://pastebin.com/QRthz5Tm)

[Config.php](https://pastebin.com/NTMKhuLk)

---

## Solved

**Solution:**

My DI, Dispatcher, and Router were all MVC versions instead of their CLI equivalents.  Changing them fixed the problem - `setTask()` was expected in the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share your `config/bootstrap.php` file? I tested with:

`use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli as DI;`

Parameters were read and line 23 was asking for `MainTask handler class` (no error).

This is the code I tested:

```
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli as CliDI;

$DI = new CliDI();

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(
    [
    'Task' => __DIR__ . '/tasks',
    ]
);
$loader->register();

$Console = new \Phalcon\CLI\Console();
$Console->setDI($DI);

$arguments = [];

foreach($argv as $k => $arg) {
    if($k == 1) {
        $arguments['task'] = $arg;
    } elseif($k == 2) {
        $arguments['action'] = $arg;
    } elseif($k >= 3) {
        $arguments['params'][] = $arg;
    }
}

try{
    $Console->handle($arguments); 
}
catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(255);
}
```

And `MainTask.php`:

```
namespace Task;

use Phalcon\Cli\Task;

class MainTask extends Task
{
    public function mainAction()
    {
        echo 'This is the default task and the default action' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function testAction(array $params)
    {
        echo sprintf('hello %s', $params[0]);

        echo PHP_EOL;

        echo sprintf('best regards, %s', $params[1]);

        echo PHP_EOL;    

    }

}
```

Comment: Links added.  How exactly did you use that code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried using `Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault\Cli` ?
I'll paste the code in a comment below, too long here.

Comment: That's what eventually fixed it.  I've updated my post with the solution.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, glad to know it helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Console->handle($arguments); // <-- This is line 23
```

It seems that this line is expecting a string and you're passing an array.

Maybe phalcon is not handling this case well and can't instantiate some other object on which it tries to call gettaskname on.

Comment: Yes, that's what the error says. $arguments is an array though.  I've checked by calling `echo gettype($arguments);` immediately before line 23.

Comment: Ah, I misread.  But that's not the case.  Passing a string gives me an error that I passed a string instead of an array.  It's expecting an array.